# To add an item to list do I need to create a new object?

Tags: c#, .net

I am adding an object to a list and then afterwards setting the object variable to null. To add the another object to the list do i need to create a new object. The code I am using is below:

```
UpdateData = new MismatchData();
   UpdateData.CINID = currentInLoopCIN_ID;
   UpdateData.ColumnMapID = <some integer>;
   UpdateData.WMSValue = <some integer>;
lsMismatchData.Add(UpdateData);
UpdateData = null;
```

Do I need to have the first line?

```
UpdateData = new MismatchData(); //Do I need to have this line of code?
```

Comment: You set the object to null, meaning the object you added to the list = null. You should make a new object everytime, but do not set it to null.

Comment: No I assign values to the object before I add to the list and then set the object to null.

Comment: @Nathan: the object in the list is not set to null. The *variable in the method* is assigned a null reference. This does not affect the list in any way; it is still containing a reference to the object instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're setting `UpdateDate` to null, you'd get an error when you'd try to set `UpdateData.CINID`, the second time around (you'd be accessing a null object).

Your null assignment is the redundant line of code here. Since you're always assigning a `new UpdateData` to your variable, you don't need to reset it in between.

With or without the null assignment, you'll still need to create a new instance every time, though, otherwise you'd just be updating the old instance.

If you want to cut down on lines of code, you could do something like this:

```
lsMismatchData.Add(new UpdateData {
    CINID = currentInLoopCIN_ID,
    ColumnMapID = <some new integer>,
    WMSValue = <some new integer>
});
```

Or, since it looks like you're in a loop, you might be able to do something like this, to make your code even terser:

```
var lsMismatchData = yourLoopSource.Select(x => new UpdateData {
    CINID = x.CIN_ID, // apply your own logic to getting the proper values here.
    ColumnMapID = x.XYZ,
    WMSValue = x.ABC
}).ToList();
```

Comment: My question after you add the item to the list, when I change the item values will that affect the just added item in the list?

Comment: If you remove the `new` assignment *and* the `null` assignment, then you will affect the already added item, yes. If you remove the `new` assignment but keep the `null` assignment, you will get an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. You need to keep the `new` assignment, but you may remove the `null` assignment.

Comment: @David thanks for the clarification, this is the explanation I was exactly looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. Otherwise `UpdateData` will be `null` and you can not access `UpdateData.CINID`.

But (using C# 3.0+) you can use the following syntax to make it shorter:

```
lsMismatchData.Add(new MismatchData() { CINID = currentInLoopCIN_ID, ColumnMapID = <x> });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll have to instantiate a new object to the variable `UpdateData` as

```
UpdateData = new MismatchData();
```

before you can start filling its properties again and also before you add it again to `lsMismatchData`, otherwise you'll get a null reference exception

Answer (score 0):

Of course, otherwise your reference is null. Then when you try to set the fields before adding the new entry you will get a NullReferenceException.

If instead you don't set it to null and modify the old object, you will modify all the other entries in the list, since they point to the same object.